# Chrome popup to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to pass an action from a popup script to the content script:

Popup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab){
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {threshold: $("#threshold").val()});
        });
    });
});
```

Content script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Content.js Loaded");
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.threshold){
            //stuff
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is //stuff is not being executed after #start is clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is threshold? You may not be getting past that if(request.threshold) statement.
You should put a console.log just before that if to check that it is true.

Comment: The code before request.threshold isn't being called either :(